# Making emacs emit a sound

Tags: emacs

While programming I am trying to impose a limit of ~ 80 characters per line. In emacs, is it 
possible to emit a loud short beep  when I cross 80 characters on a line?

Comment: What OS, please?  Don't worry about the negative down-votes (I fixed the first one, but I can only do that one time) -- I usually end up answering my own questions on superuser.  Here is an OSX specific example:  `(defun sound () "This is a shell command process for afplay filename."  (interactive) (start-process "hello-world" nil "afplay" "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.sound/blow.aiff"))`

Comment: If you type `M-x eval-expression RET (beep) RET` do you hear any sound coming from your computer speakers?

Answer (score 1):

Not all operating systems support playing sounds using Emacs. But for those that do, you can find the relevant information in the Elisp manual, node [`Sound Output`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sound-Output.html).

As that doc tells you, "*The sound must be stored as a file in RIFF-WAVE format (`.wav`) or
Sun Audio format (`.au`).*"

You can use function `play-sound` or command `play-sound-file` to play the sound.